# MATLAB linking wrong OpenCV folder (OS X)

Tags: macos, matlab, opencv, mex, conflicting-libraries

I'm running some MATLAB code (OpenTLD) that calls OpenCV, however it appears I have duplicates of some of the dylibs which is confusing MATLAB.

```
__ZN2cv13AlgorithmInfo8addParamERNS_9AlgorithmEPKcRbbMS1_FivEMS1_FviERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNSA_11char_traitsIcEENSA_9allocatorIcEEEE
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.2.4.dylib
  Expected in:
  /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libopencv_core.2.4.dylib
 in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.2.4.dylib
```

I definitely do have the libopencv dylibs where it thinks they should be.

This is the relevant part of the compilation:

```
include = ' -I/usr/local/include/opencv/ -I/usr/local/include/'; 
libpath = '/usr/local/lib/'; 

files = dir([libpath 'libopencv*.dylib']);

lib = [];
for i = 1:length(files),
    lib = [lib ' ' libpath files(i).name];
end

eval(['mex lk.cpp -O' include lib]);
```

My current thought is to make a soft link, but I think that would mess up other OpenCV stuff I do outside of MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

Try seting `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` environment variable before starting MATLAB to force it to use your local libraries instead of its own. Something like:

```
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/lib/libopencv_2.4.dylib /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/matlab
```

Use `ldd` (or the OSX equivalent `otool`) both inside and outside MATLAB to find which shared libraries are the source of the conflict. Compare the output of these two:

```
% in MATLAB command window
>> !ldd ./some_mex_file.mex*
```

and

```
# in system shell
$ ldd ./some_mex_file.mex*
```